# What is the behavior of std::move when a constructor is being implicitly called?

Tags: c++, stl, copy, move

I came across the following behavior today and had a question regarding its inner workings.

I had a vector of strings that I needed to convert to filesystem paths, and I did so with the copy method, knowing it would call the appropriate string constructor.

```
std::vector<std::string> strings;
std::vector<boost::filesystem::path> paths;
std::copy(strings.begin(), strings.end(), std::back_inserter(paths));
```

Normally if I wasn't converting and didn't need the old collection anymore, I would use `std::move()` to save resources. But I figured `std::copy()` would be a better call here considering I would be implicitly creating new objects. But out of morbid curiosity I tried calling `std::move()` anyway, not expecting it to work. And it did work!

```
std::vector<std::string> strings;
std::vector<boost::filesystem::path> paths;
std::move(strings.begin(), strings.end(), std::back_inserter(paths));
```

Does someone know what's going on under the hood here? What's the state of the input array after this? Is it unsafe? Are the strings being copied anyway, or are they actually moved into the constructed object?

Comment: Why don't you use debugger and step into `std::move` call to see what is going on under the hood yourself?

Comment: @VTT I know what's going on under the hood at least for clang in this one instance (objects are constructed and the strings still appear to be in the original vector), but I was more interested in terms of what the standard guarantees in every case, and which call would be considered safest or most appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by others it has no affect as the current destination `boost::filesystem::path` does not use r-value reference in its constructor.

But also as mentioned a `move` maybe more effecient in the future as any changes will allow the code to become more effecient without any changes in your source.

**BUT** rather than copying into the structure why not construct with move.

```
std::vector<boost::filesystem::path> paths;
std::copy(strings.begin(), strings.end(), std::back_inserter(paths));
```

Can be written as:

```
std::vector<boost::filesystem::path> paths(
                                      std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(paths)),
                                      std::make_move_iterator(std::end(paths)));
```

Comment: Didn't realize that was available. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Both variants are safe and should work. Right now (boost 1.66) there is no benefits of using `move` because there is no `boost::filesystem::path` constructor taking source string by rvalue reference (and moving it). If it is going to be added in the future then second variant may be preferred.

However both variants will stop compiling if boost devs decide to finally declare constructor taking source string as `explicit`. So better approach would be to move manually. This code will work regardless of whether corresponding path constructor is `explicit` or not and may utilize constructor taking an rvalue reference when it gets implemented:

```
paths.reserve(strings.size());
for(auto & source_path: strings)
{
    paths.emplace_back(::std::move(source_path));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no difference between using `std::copy` and `std::move` in your example, since there is no `boost::filesystem::path(string&&)` constructor.

But it might get added in a future version.

In general, you should assume an object is in a moved-from state after using `std::move` on it.

So if you never use `strings` afterwards (unless reset), use `std::move`.
Otherwise use `std::copy`. Right now there will be no difference in performance.